# how will exit from the whole function if another function is false and situated inside main function?

Tags: javascript

I have any code.I pointed out that function's 'alertError' conditions. If false i have to exit from whole code. How can i do that? i pointed out inside 'alertError' return false , but that don't work.

```
function pickUpMounth(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alertError(this.lol.value - 1);
   let month = mounts.filter((e, i) => i == this.lol.value - 1)
   output.innerHTML = month;
}
form.addEventListener('submit', pickUpMounth);
function alertError(value) {
   if (value > mounts.length) {
      alert('there are not many months in a year');
      return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value returned by `alertError()`

```
if (alertError(this.lol.value - 1) === false) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: thx , it's so easy:) can i use inside func. throw new Error()?